# How to set Express route alias to html file?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to serve some static file with a nicer url endpoints.

For example, `/home` will serve `/public/home.html`.

I can probably use `res.sendfile()` in the route config, but sendfile will not cache the file output in production mode so I am not too sure if this is a good solution.

How do I set routes to act like an alias to a html file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this.

```
var express = require('express');
var app =express.createServer();
// ------
app.get('/home', function(req,res){
 res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/home.html');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am using at the moment but was advised against it as it doesn't cache the file and will be bad for production mode.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer if it doesn't really solve your problem related to caching?

Answer (score 4):

There's a module called [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) that provides cacheing functionality. You also might be able to just use symlinks. You might be better served with nginx's `try_files` or another non-node.js reverse proxy for this functionality.

For a while, there was a `staticCache` middleware built into express that would do the cacheing. It was [removed from connect in January 2014](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/commit/ec30812d59efdb2f11a81302e952272752c49be1).[Here's the github issue where TJ explains staticCache being deprecated](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/617).

Comment: http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/9682643240/connect-1-7-0-fast-static-file-memory-cache-and-more is a dead link.