# How do I assign a HTML file to a certain link

Tags: html, cpanel

So I have all my HTML, CSS, and JS files ready to be uploaded to a server (Using cPanel as I have experience with them). But i was wondering how to assign a HTML file to a certain link like "devwebdevelopment.com/about" or something like that

What I want is to have a link with a "/". For ex. "google.com/developers"

Comment: You can use Express routing to do this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148845/how-to-set-express-route-alias-to-html-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webservers are very similar to windows folders in a windows PC.

For example, think of www.google.com as a folder called "home". In this "home" folder, this is your root directory, where you serve the index.html for the home page.

Now in your case, the "www.google.com/developer" is created doing... you guessed it, creating another folder in your "home" directory.

Example: in your root directory of "home" (in web servers this is called the public I believe), just create another folder called "developer". Now your website is structured as:

www.mywebsite.com and www.mywebsite.com/developer

In your developer, create an "index.html" file, which will be the first file served to the client upon initial http request.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now just to clarify, I make a "public" folder in the server and then in that folder make another folder with what I want after the "/"

Comment: It depends on who is hosting your website. Most web servers / hosting companies already provide you with a public folder. Usually you don't make the public folder. 

When you open your file system, for example if you have access to Cpanel, you should have access to something called "File manager" When you open "File Manager" that should automatically bring you to your public root directory. 

If this satisfies as the answer, please mark it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a directory with the desired name.

Let's say you want to add a / contact

For this, just follow this directory structure

index.html
contact (this is a folder)
gallery (this is another folder)

And play the files for each folder. If my answer does not help you, comment here so I can help you.

Comment: I kinda get what you are saying to do, but how would I actually do it

Comment: This, just create a new folder inside your www with the name contact for example

Comment: And within your html you create a link to contact / contact.html